# In some Java code, why does the class Deck extend the Card class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, ooad

I am reading some code in Java, which I am not familiar with, but it seems weird that if a class is `Deck` (for a deck of cards), it already has an instance variable of an array of `Cards`, so why does `Deck` extend or inherit `Card`?  I thought class A inherits class B only if A is a B (Cat inherits Animal because a cat is an animal).

The code is below:

```
public class Deck <T extends Card> {
    private ArrayList<T> cards;
    private int dealtIndex = 0; // marks first undealt card

    public Deck() {
    }

    public void setDeckOfCards(ArrayList<T> deckOfCards) {
        cards = deckOfCards;
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {

    [...]
}

public abstract class Card {
    private boolean available = true;

    /* number or face that's on card - a number 2 through 10, 
     * or 11 for Jack, 12 for Queen, 13 for King, or 1 for Ace 
     */
    protected int faceValue;
    protected Suit suit;

    public Card(int c, Suit s) {
        faceValue = c;
        suit = s;
    }

    public abstract int value();

    public Suit suit() { 
        return suit; 
    }

    [...]

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 public class Deck <T extends Card>
```

Deck *does not* extend Card.

This is a generic type annotation, and it says that a Deck can be of type T where T is a subclass of Card.

This is the same as Java's collection classes, where a List of String also does not extend String (but contains String instances).

This allows you to write code like:

```
Deck<PokerCard> pokerDeck = new Deck<PokerCard>();

PokerCard c = pokerDeck.getTopCard();   
// now you know it is a PokerCard, not just any old card

pokerDeck.insert(new MagicTheGatheringCard()); 
// get a compile error for wrong card type
```

Comment: I always play Poker with my Pokemon cards, makes it much more intense!

Answer (score 2):

The class deck *does not extend Card*.  It contains contains an ArrayList of Cards.

The `<T extends Card>` notation is a little confusing, but it means that this Deck is "parametized" by T, which must extend, (be a subclass of) Cards.  So it could be Pinochle Cards, Bridge Cards, Tarot Cards etc...   e.g.

```
Deck myTarot = new Deck<TarotCard>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You interpreted it the wrong way. You should read class Deck of T (which extends Card). Like so you have an `List<Something>`(list of something) you have here `Deck<Cards>` (a deck of cards). That could be also a `Deck<PokerCard>`, if PokerCard extends Card

Answer (score 0):

A class extends another class when it wants to inherit properties of that class.
for eg.

```
Class A{

public void show()
{
//something to show
}
}

Class B extends A{

//B can now enjoy the show() function defined by A
}
```

This is how inheritance work.

Cat will extend Animal because, cat is a subset of animal, it can come under that category.

Here Deck does not extend card.